# GStreamer, streaming and taking a shot at the same time

Tags: streaming, gstreamer, v4l

Does GStreamer (Linux) support streaming and taking a shot in a different resolution at the same time?

I need to stream a V4L device at 720p using h264. Everything is workings so far. Now I want to take a single shot (jpeg/png) from time to time at 1080p without interrupting the video stream.

I guess I have to read 1080p from the V4L device, encode the data towards 720p for streaming and use the raw 1080p as source for my single shots.

My preferred solution would be to trigger the single shots on demand, but taking a shot every half second should be OK, too. Does GStreamer support such application by command line or do I have to programm aganist GStreamer lib?

@edit: I have to check out if it is possible to read from the same V4L device at the same time and let Linux do the multiplexing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "tee" does the job.

Example pipeline:

```
gst-launch-0.10 videotestsrc ! tee name=tp \
    tp. ! queue ! video/x-raw-rgb, framerate=25/1, width=640, height=360 ! ximagesink \
    tp. ! queue ! video/x-raw-rgb, framerate=25/1, width=640, height=360 ! ximagesink
```